# Is the Vigenère Cryptosystem malleable?

Tags: classical-cipher, vigenere, malleability

Is the Vigenère Cryptosystem malleable, and how can we prove that it is (or it is not) malleable?

Comment: What research have you done? Also, can you give your (mathematical) description of vigenere?

Comment: I΄m sorry. I΄m new here and i couldn΄t find how to write the math description. I have the one given by Florian Bourse below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vigenere Cryptosystem is as follow:

You chose a key $(K_0,...,K_{m-1})$ consisting of elements in $Z_{26}$. 
Then a ciphertext for the message $(M_0,...,M_{n-1})$ is $$(M_i+K_{i\mod m}\mod 26)_{i \in [0..n-1]}$$

It is easy to see that you can generate a ciphertext for the message $(M_0+1,...,M_{n-1}+1)$ by adding 1 to each letter. It is therefore by definition malleable.